# Converting web optimised canvas game for phonegap/jqm

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile, html5-canvas

I've previously developed a canvas game intended for a web browser however I would like to incorporate it into a phonegap/query mobile app that I am currently building without rewriting huge amounts of the game. I have a few issues to overcome however.

1. The game is landscape, how can I set it to be permanently in landscape view (I thought of a rotated div?)
2. What's the best way of fixing its size (as it is currently 800 x 500)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. To permanently set the orientation to landscape just set this in xcode (there is an orientation dropdown on the main info screen). Phonegap/xcode take care of this for you.
2. Are you just wanting to shrink (<= 3GS) / expand (>= 4) your app view? What about retina screens? You can use css for this but the exact code will depend on your needs.